# How to draw two images on the bottom right corner of the screen programatically? (without using XML files)

Tags: android, imageview

i need to draw two imageviews, (+) and (-) symbols, on the bottom right corner of the screen, similar of the zoom objects from googlemaps.

I need to do it programatically, with Java, and without using XML files.

I'm trying to do with relativelayout, but i dont know how to do it. They must to be on the bottom right corner of the screen, with 5 or 10 pixels of separation between them.

How to do it?

Also will be cool if someone can tell me how to detect when a user has pressed each image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use gravity.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#setGravity(int)

this might do it:

```
image.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

Comment: i have two images... if i use that one is draw on te same position as the other.

Comment: use this on the 2nd image. image2.offsetLeftAndRight(-100); Then it's places 100px left of the right picture. You might wanna use the width of the 1. image + a couple of pixels (for padding) and use the negative number of that.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
ImageView plusImage = new ImageView(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams pp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
pp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
pp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
pp.leftMargin = 5;
plusImage.setId(501);
plusImage.setLayoutParams(pp);
plusImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

ImageView minusImage = new ImageView(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
mp.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF,plusImage.getId());
mp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
mp.rightMargin = 5;
minusImage.setId(502);
minusImage.setLayoutParams(mp);
minusImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

//Add the images to the outer layout   
((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.outerlayout)).addView(plusImage);
((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.outerlayout)).addView(minusImage);
```